# How to move items to left inside a div?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

I have a label,checkboxlist and a datagridview within a div. I have used inline css to move items left. But it doesn't work as i expect. How can i move them? I want all the three items in a row. Below i have added my aspx code.

```html
<div id="div2" style="width:100%; height:auto; margin-top:30px">
        <div id="div21" style="width: 50%; height:auto">
            <div id="div211" style=" width:15%; height:auto">
                <asp:Label ID="lblKPI" Text="KPI :" runat="server" style="margin-top:10px; margin-left:20px">
                </asp:Label>
            </div>
            <div id="div212" style=" width:60%; height:auto; float:left">
                <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chklstKPI" style="width:auto; height:auto" runat="server">
                </asp:CheckBoxList>
            </div>                                 
        </div>        
        
        
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" style="float:left">
            
        </asp:GridView>
    
    </div>
```

Comment: try `text-align:left;` on the div to align all the elements inside it

Comment: can you provide the `view source code` of the HTML ? so that we can look at the issue.

Comment: Better to use table with three column  its works better

Comment: @stack there is no source code yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap `gridview` in `div` and set `float:left` to that div. Also inner div needs to have `float:left` as well.

Try below html

```
<div id="div2" style="width:100%; height:auto; margin-top:30px">
        <div id="div21" style="width: 50%; height:auto;float:left">
            <div id="div211" style=" width:15%; height:auto;float:left">
                <asp:Label ID="lblKPI" Text="KPI :" runat="server" style="margin-top:10px; margin-left:20px">
                </asp:Label>
            </div>
            <div id="div212" style=" width:60%; height:auto; float:left">
                <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chklstKPI" style="width:auto; height:auto" runat="server">
                </asp:CheckBoxList>
            </div>                                 
        </div>        

        <div  style="float:left;width:45%">


        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SomeText">

                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set float : left in style property of div 
here i give you one example simply try to copy paste it

```js
<div id="div2" style="width:100%; height:auto; margin-top:30px; position:absolute">
        <div id="div21" style="width: 50%; height:auto">
            <div id="div211" style=" width:15%; height:auto">
                <asp:Label ID="lblKPI" Text="KPI :" runat="server" style="margin-top:10px; margin-left:200px; position:absolute">
                </asp:Label>
            </div>
            <div id="div212" style=" width:60%; margin-left:200px; height:auto; float:left">
                <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chklstKPI" style="width:auto; height:auto" runat="server">
                </asp:CheckBoxList>
            </div>                                 
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place gridview in a div and set `float:left;` property for that div

try this please:

```
<div id="div2" style="width: 100%; height: auto; margin-top: 30px">
    <div id="div21" style="width: 50%; height: auto; float: left;">
        <div id="div211" style="width: 15%; height: auto">
            <asp:Label ID="lblKPI" Text="KPI :" runat="server" Style="margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 20px">
            </asp:Label>
        </div>
        <div id="div212" style="width: 60%; height: auto; float: left">
            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chklstKPI" Style="width: auto; height: auto" runat="server">
            </asp:CheckBoxList>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="div22" style="width: 45%; height: auto; float: left;">
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Style="float: left">
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add style to the divs:

```html
<div id="div2" style="width:100%; height:auto; margin-top:30px; text-align: left;">
        <div id="div21" style="width: 50%; height:auto; display: inline;">
            <div id="div211" style=" width:15%; height:auto; display: inline;">
                <asp:Label ID="lblKPI" Text="KPI :" runat="server" style="margin-top:10px; margin-left:20px">
                </asp:Label>
            </div>
            <div id="div212" style=" width:60%; height:auto; float:left; display: inline;">
                <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chklstKPI" style="width:auto; height:auto" runat="server">
                </asp:CheckBoxList>
            </div>                                 
        </div>        
        <div style="display: inline; width:50%">

        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" style="float:left">

        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    </div>
```